# How to obtain the original matrix after performing symrcm or symamd in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I use the Cuthill-McKee algorithm. After finding the desired vector, I need to restore the original matrix. I found the answer here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94946-how-do-i-obtain-the-original-mapping-after-performing-symrcm-in-matlab-7-1-r14sp3 but for my images I get "Index exceeds matrix dimensions". Is there any other way to do this? (Preferably without the availability of the original matrix)

```matlab
symV %original matrix
k1 = symrcm(symV)
matrix_after_cm = symV(k1,k1);
spy(first_after_cm)
```

Comment: can't you copy the matrix to a new variable before doing the computations?
`symV_orignal = symV; k1=symrcm(symV); ...`.

Comment: I meant that the original matrix will not be available

Answer (score 0):

I was answered the question here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/484202-how-to-obtain-the-original-matrix-after-performing-symrcm-or-symamd-in-matlab?s_tid=ab_old_mlc_ans_email_view#comment_754323

Final solution is

```
[~,q] = sort(k1);
AfromB = first_after_cm(q,q);  % Elapsed time is 0.002503 seconds.
norm(AfromB-symV)  % ans = 0
```